# RecyclerView Q&A

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a Q&A where each question is a card.  The answer starts showing the first line, but when its clicked it should expanded to show the full answer.

When an answer is expanded/collapsed the rest of the RecyclerView should animate to make room for the expansion or collapse to avoid showing a blank space.

I watched the talk on [RecyclerView animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imsr8NrIAMs), and believe I want a custom ItemAnimator, where I override animateChange.  At that point I should create an ObjectAnimator to animate the height of the View's LayoutParams.  Unfortunately I'm having a hard time tying it all together. I also return true when overriding canReuseUpdatedViewHolder, so we reuse the same viewholder.

```
@Override
public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean animateChange(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder,
                             @NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder,
                             @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preInfo,
                             @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postInfo) {
    Log.d("test", "Run custom animation.");

    final ColorsAdapter.ColorViewHolder holder = (ColorsAdapter.ColorViewHolder) newHolder;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) holder.tvColor.getLayoutParams();
    ObjectAnimator halfSize = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(holder.tvColor.getLayoutParams(), "height", params.height, 0);
    halfSize.start();
    return super.animateChange(oldHolder, newHolder, preInfo, postInfo);
}
```

Right now I'm just trying to get something to animate, but nothing happens...  Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer as I saw it wasn't quite what you were asking for.

Comment: @George Mulligan its working fine great

Comment: @eimmer have you resolved problem.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan's answer is the best one I saw.  I'm working on a github project to provide full examples of working code that you can find here. https://github.com/rvail2/RecyclerViewHeightAnimations

Comment: did u see my answer @eimmer, try that also it is also good answer, btw georgeMulligan is also very good

Comment: This github link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your animation was not working because you cannot animate `LayoutParams` that way although it would be neat if you could. I tried the code you had and all it did was make my view jump to the new height. Only way I found to get this to work was to use a `ValueAnimator` as you can see in the example below.

I noticed some shortcomings when using the `DefaultItemAnimator` to show/hide a view by updating its visibility. Although it did make room for the new view and animated the rest of the items up and down based on the visibility of the expandable view, I noticed it did not animate the height of the expandable view. It simply faded into place and out of place using alpha value only.

Below is a custom `ItemAnimator` that has size and alpha animations based on hiding/showing a `LinearLayout` in the `ViewHolder` layout. It also allows the reuse of the same `ViewHolder` and attempts handling partial animations correctly if the user taps the header quickly:

```
public static class MyAnimator extends DefaultItemAnimator {
    @Override
    public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return true;
    }

    private HashMap<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, AnimatorState> animatorMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean animateChange(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder, @NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postInfo) {
        final ValueAnimator heightAnim;
        final ObjectAnimator alphaAnim;

        final CustomAdapter.ViewHolder vh = (CustomAdapter.ViewHolder) newHolder;
        final View expandableView = vh.getExpandableView();
        final int toHeight; // save height for later in case reversing animation

        if(vh.isExpanded()) {
            expandableView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // measure expandable view to get correct height
            expandableView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            toHeight = expandableView.getMeasuredHeight();
            alphaAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandableView, "alpha", 1f);
        } else {
            toHeight = 0;
            alphaAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandableView, "alpha", 0f);
        }

        heightAnim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(expandableView.getHeight(), toHeight);
        heightAnim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                expandableView.getLayoutParams().height = (Integer) heightAnim.getAnimatedValue();
                expandableView.requestLayout();
            }
        });

        AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet()
                .setDuration(getChangeDuration());
        animSet.playTogether(heightAnim, alphaAnim);
        animSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            private boolean isCanceled;

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if(!vh.isExpanded() && !isCanceled) {
                    expandableView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                dispatchChangeFinished(vh, false);
                animatorMap.remove(newHolder);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                isCanceled = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) { }
        });

        AnimatorState animatorState = animatorMap.get(newHolder);
        if(animatorState != null) {
            animatorState.animSet.cancel();

            // animation already running. Set start current play time of
            // new animations to keep them smooth for reverse animation
            alphaAnim.setCurrentPlayTime(animatorState.alphaAnim.getCurrentPlayTime());
            heightAnim.setCurrentPlayTime(animatorState.heightAnim.getCurrentPlayTime());

            animatorMap.remove(newHolder);
        }

        animatorMap.put(newHolder, new AnimatorState(alphaAnim, heightAnim, animSet));

        dispatchChangeStarting(newHolder, false);
        animSet.start();

        return false;
    }

    public static class AnimatorState {
        final ValueAnimator alphaAnim, heightAnim;
        final AnimatorSet animSet;

        public AnimatorState(ValueAnimator alphaAnim, ValueAnimator heightAnim, AnimatorSet animSet) {
            this.alphaAnim = alphaAnim;
            this.heightAnim = heightAnim;
            this.animSet = animSet;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result using a slightly modified `RecyclerView` demo.

[image]

**Update:**

Just noticed your use case  is actually a bit different after rereading the question. You have a text view and only want to show a single line of it and then later expand it to show all lines. Fortunately that simplifies the custom animator:

```
public static class MyAnimator extends DefaultItemAnimator {
    @Override
    public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return true;
    }

    private HashMap<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, ValueAnimator> animatorMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean animateChange(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder, @NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postInfo) {
        ValueAnimator prevAnim = animatorMap.get(newHolder);
        if(prevAnim != null) {
            prevAnim.reverse();
            return false;
        }

        final ValueAnimator heightAnim;
        final CustomAdapter.ViewHolder vh = (CustomAdapter.ViewHolder) newHolder;
        final TextView tv = vh.getExpandableTextView();

        if(vh.isExpanded()) {
            tv.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((View) tv.getParent()).getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            heightAnim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(tv.getHeight(), tv.getMeasuredHeight());
        } else {
            Paint.FontMetrics fm = tv.getPaint().getFontMetrics();
            heightAnim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(tv.getHeight(), (int)(Math.abs(fm.top) + Math.abs(fm.bottom)));
        }

        heightAnim.setDuration(getChangeDuration());
        heightAnim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                tv.getLayoutParams().height = (Integer) heightAnim.getAnimatedValue();
                tv.requestLayout();
            }
        });

        heightAnim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                dispatchChangeFinished(vh, false);
                animatorMap.remove(newHolder);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) { }
        });

        animatorMap.put(newHolder, heightAnim);

        dispatchChangeStarting(newHolder, false);
        heightAnim.start();

        return false;
    }
}
```

And the new demo:

[image]

Comment: I think this is the best answer for getting the animations correct.  NOTE: Keeping track of the animations in the viewholder could be problematic when ViewHolders are being recycled.

Comment: @eimmer Your note is a good point but I thought the `ViewHolder` will not be recycled while there is an ongoing animation. Yigit mentions in his [blog](http://www.birbit.com/recyclerview-animations-part-1-how-animations-work/) that views can be removed by the `LayoutManager` but stay in the `RecyclerView` so animations behave properly. I wish I could find the source code to the video so we can see what they are doing to reverse the animation.

Comment: @eimmer Very interesting point as I am trying to achieve exactly that. But after looking at Chet Haas' 2015 Android Summit video, I can see you are not using `recordPreLayoutInformation` nor `recordPostLayoutInformation` that capture values before binding the VH and after binding VH when calling `notifyItemChanged`. In my case, this causes the below items to quickly translate down, only to translate back up and only then to nicely follow the height animation. Would your approach be better ? I am really trying hard to stick to Chet Haas' explanations as he his behind the Recyclerview. Thanks !

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to implement a custom `ItemAnimator` the default `DefaultItemAnimator` already supports what you need. However you need to tell this Animator which views changed. I guess you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your adapter. This prevents the animation for a single changed item in the RecyclerView (in your case the expand/collapse of the item).

You should use `notifyItemChanged(int position)` for the items that were changed. Here is a short `itemClicked(int position)` method that expands/collapses views in the RecyclerView. The field `expandedPosition` keeps track of the currently expanded item:

```
private void itemClicked(int position) {
    if (expandedPosition == -1) {
        // selected first item
        expandedPosition = position;
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    } else if (expandedPosition == position) {
        // collapse currently expanded item
        expandedPosition = -1;
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    } else {
        // collapse previously expanded item and expand new item
        int oldExpanded = expandedPosition;
        expandedPosition = position;
        notifyItemChanged(oldExpanded);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: How do you actually collapse the view then?  Do you just set it's height to 0? Set the visibility to GONE?  Apply a custom animation?

Comment: @eimmer every time you call `notifyItemChanged`, the method `onBindViewHolder` in your adapter is called for the relevant positions. It is sufficient to provide the expanded version of the element to get the animation. The item views in the gif are just two `TextViews` in a `LinearLayout`. The difference between the collapsed/expanded version is a longer text in the second `TextView`

Comment: This is a simple and neat approach but it does have some shortcomings. The ViewHolders in this case are swapped by doing a fade and the actual change in size of the changed item is not animated. It isn't noticeable in this example since you are only extending the text but if you replaced the text entirely with something different the text would overlap from the old and new view holders. Also, since the height isn't animated it is awkward if the user expands and collapses quickly. Maybe I did something wrong when testing but I wrote a custom animator to try and overcome these issues below.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation, you need to return false in animateChange or call runPendingAnimations later. Try returning false.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this class:

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by ankitagrawal on 2/14/16.
 */

public class AnimatedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int originalHeight = 0;
    private boolean mIsViewExpanded = false;
    private TextView textView;

    // ..... CODE ..... //
    public AnimatedViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Initialize other views, like TextView, ImageView, etc. here

        // If isViewExpanded == false then set the visibility
        // of whatever will be in the expanded to GONE

        if (!mIsViewExpanded) {
            // Set Views to View.GONE and .setEnabled(false)
            textView.setLines(1);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {

        // Declare a ValueAnimator object
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator;
        if(mIsViewExpanded) {
            view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((View) view.getParent()).getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            mIsViewExpanded = false;
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.getHeight(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
        } else {
            Paint.FontMetrics fm = ((TextView)view).getPaint().getFontMetrics();
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.getHeight(), (int) (Math.abs(fm.top) + Math.abs(fm.bottom)));
            mIsViewExpanded = true;
        }
        valueAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) { }
        });

        valueAnimator.setDuration(200);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                view.getLayoutParams().height = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                view.requestLayout();
            }
        });


        valueAnimator.start();

    }
}
```

The Advantage of this approach is it only add animation to onClick event and that best suits your requirement.

adding animation to viewholder will be too burdensome to your requirement.
and itemAnimator as per doc are animation for layout out items so also not best suits your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

For expand & collapse animation android there is github library for it.
[ExpandableRecyclerView](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view)

> 1).Add dependencies in the `build.gradle`  file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'
}
```

[Image of Expand & Collapse Animation](https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2015/08/expandable_recycler_example.gif)

> 2) Expand & Collapse animation for RecyclerView animation

```
public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int originalHeight = 0;
    private boolean isViewExpanded = false;
    private YourCustomView yourCustomView

    public ExampleViewHolder(View v) {
     super(v);
     v.setOnClickListener(this);

     // Initialize other views, like TextView, ImageView, etc. here

     // If isViewExpanded == false then set the visibility 
     // of whatever will be in the expanded to GONE

     if (isViewExpanded == false) {
         // Set Views to View.GONE and .setEnabled(false)
         yourCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         yourCustomView.setEnabled(false);
     }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        // If the originalHeight is 0 then find the height of the View being used 
        // This would be the height of the cardview
        if (originalHeight == 0) {
                originalHeight = view.getHeight();
            }

        // Declare a ValueAnimator object
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator;
            if (!mIsViewExpanded) {
                yourCustomView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                yourCustomView.setEnabled(true);
                mIsViewExpanded = true;
                valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, originalHeight + (int) (originalHeight * 2.0)); // These values in this method can be changed to expand however much you like
            } else {
                mIsViewExpanded = false;
                valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight + (int) (originalHeight * 2.0), originalHeight);

                Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f); // Fade out

                a.setDuration(200);
                // Set a listener to the animation and configure onAnimationEnd
                a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        yourCustomView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        yourCustomView.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });

                // Set the animation on the custom view
                yourCustomView.startAnimation(a);
            }
            valueAnimator.setDuration(200);
            valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    view.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                    view.requestLayout();
                }
            });
            valueAnimator.start();
    }

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You do not need an external library when android does this natively.

Comment: From the sample provided by NerdRanch, this uses two separate view holders.  These seems like an absolute last resort if nothing else works.